# How can I remove this sym link

Tags: centos, rm, rmdir

I created a symlink, and I'm trying to remove it using  `rm /WebRoot` it but I get the error **Is a directory**, but if I try `rmdir /WebRoot` I get an error **Not a directory**.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `rm foo` with no trailing slash.